# Split "" in a str py

Tags: python, string, split

so i got this question and it´s I have a str like this:

```
"Factura,FE8868""Valor,795,000.00,850,000.00,140,000.00,1,450,000.00""Total,3,235,000.00""CECO,101,0,111,105""PLANILLAS,21999/21300/21304/23975/23946/25706/25714/23966/23977/23913/23941"
```

And what i want to split every "" to get sometime like this: (A variable for each split result)

```
n1 = "Factura,FE8868"
n2 = "Valor,795,000.00,850,000.00,140,000.00,1,450,000.00"
n3 = "Total,3,235,000.00" 
n4 = "CECO,101,0,111,105"
n5 = "PLANILLAS,21999/21300/21304/23975/23946/25706/25714/23966/23977/23913/23941"
```

Note, if i try to declarate a variable with the whole str before split it, get an error due a variable is `var = "some in here"` and this one would looks like `var = " "some""thing""here" "`

How could i do it?

Comment: could be an x y problem. You don't actually have the string you say you do at the start anyway - its not valid Python.

Comment: @L.Grozinger What do you mean with not valid Python?

Comment: @L.Grozinger It is valid Python. The tokens delimited by double-quotes will be concatenated to form one string

Comment: string.split(separator('"')); but you'll problably end up into some trouble. Try to change the response string to a json response or another format that can assist you better.

Comment: @PedroSerpa Apart from the initial and final double-quotes shown in the question, there are no more occurrences in that string

Comment: Albert Winestein, you're right. Ignore, please.

Comment: Hm I didn't know `"` would concatenate strings like that, wow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ways you can achieve this.

Use single quotes: `'` (assuming you don't have any `'` in the string itself)

```
var = '" "some""thing""here" "'
```

Use triple-quotes (either `'''` or `"""`)

```
var = """"" "some""thing""here" """"
```

You can also do this by escaping `"` with `\"` when they're part of the string (but probably the least aesthetic solution):

```
var = "\" \"some\"\"thing\"\"here\" \""
```

---

```
data = '"Factura,FE8868""Valor,795,000.00,850,000.00,140,000.00,1,450,000.00""Total,3,235,000.00""CECO,101,0,111,105""PLANILLAS,21999/21300/21304/23975/23946/25706/25714/23966/23977/23913/23941"'

# split('"') on the original string does not result in
# what you want based on your question (e.g. leading " is
# considered a 'split' that ends up being an empty string
# Because the string you gave us begins with a leading "
# and ending ", one way to do what you want is to split
# and then remove any empty fields in the resulting split

n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 = [i for i in data.split('"') if i]

print(n1)
print(n2)
print(n3)
print(n4)
print(n5)
```

Comment: with both answers, yours and @Dave Cook, i got the same result, the same first str, it's like doesn't split it =(

Comment: @LuizVillalba I answered your question about how to actually declare a variable that has the string you gave us. But when you call `split('"')` on your original string, more than 5 things are returned because, for example, `""` is considered two different splits. However, look at my new edited code which is an example of how to split your original string. If all your data looks exactly like that (leading/ending quotes), it will work.

Comment: Now i understand better how this work, and as you said, it worked perfectly thanks a lot, friend

Answer (score 1):

First, when you write your code, use single quotes when declaring the string. That way, the double quotes in the string won't make python thing the string has finished.

Then you can split your string easily. Try this:

```
s = '"Factura,FE8868""Valor,795,000.00,850,000.00,140,000.00,1,450,000.00""Total,3,235,000.00""CECO,101,0,111,105""PLANILLAS,21999/21300/21304/23975/23946/25706/25714/23966/23977/23913/23941"'
s.split('""')
```